# QUnitAdaptor for JSTestDriver passing failed test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

Using QUnitAdaptor to test my QUnit tests, it actually passed a test which is supposed to fail:

```
test("very simple test", function() {
var somevar = true;
equals(somevar, false, "test");
});
```

The above test passed when I ran it after capturing browser programmatically.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?  If so, how did you get around it?  I'm using QUnitAdaptor1.1 with equiv.js, Asserts.js and JSTestDriver1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue, kind of: it seems that if you've already ran the suite once and then add this test, no new tests turn out (and it passes). Only by restarting the server and recapturing the browser the test was actually added in the suite and failed as it should have in the first place.

Don't know if this is of any help to you, but I'd nevertheless suggest you to restart the server and recapture the browser and then try again.